# How to Create/Import a CodeFormatter profile via plugin (programmatically) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to define a common code formatting profile in Eclipse CDT and share it with others as plugin.

I figured out how to do it manually (Using Export & Import options) but i would like to handle it programmatically so that users are not required to perform it manually.

Here is how i expect the profile to be available for users to select.
[image]

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21273017

Comment: @LuisMuñoz i tried the code from the link. Export works fine but import throws exceptions and after that my eclipse itself misbehaves and finally i had to close it.